# json_encode retornando "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded"

Tags: php, json, codificação-de-caracteres, php-domdocument

Estou utilizando o `Laravel 3` em um determinado sistema.

As vezes estou tendo um problema com o `json_encode`, que está retornando `false` em alguns casos.

Nesse código, carrego uma página externa e, com o `DomDocument`, faço um `foreach` nas meta tags e capturo o valor do conteúdo, salvando num `array`.

Esse `array` eu utilizo o `Response::json` do `Laravel`, que internamente usa o `json_encode`.

Mais ou menos assim:

```
$url = Input::get('url');
$html = file_get_contents($url);

$dom = new DOMDocument();

@$dom->loadHtml('<?xml encoding="UTF-8" version="1.0"?>' . $html);

$dados = array();

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $element) {

    $name = trim($element->getAttribute('property'));

    if (! $name || strpos($name, 'og:') === false) continue;

    $dados[$name] = $element->getAttribute('content');
}

return Response::json($dados);
```

Quando utilizo `Response::json`, está me retornando vazio, em alguns casos.

Daí eu fiz a seguinte verificação para saber o que estava errado:

```
$json = json_encode($dados);

   if ($json === false) {
      echo json_last_error_msg();
   }
```

E ele retornou:

> Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Verifiquei o conteúdo da variável `$dados`, e ela estava assim:

```
Array
(
    [og:title] => **Removido**
    [og:description] => Os Dez Mandamentos: chuva de granizo e fogo � a sétima praga a castigar o Egito
    [og:image] => **Removido**
)
```

Parece que o problema está sendo gerado por causa desse caractere `�`.

Alguém sabe como posso contornar esse problema?

## Atualização

Fiz o teste de tentar imprimir o conteúdo o html com o `DomDocument`, usando `$dom->saveHTML()` e me foi retornado esse erro:

> output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xE9 0x20 0x61 0x20

Comment: O mais estranho é que a letra `é` aparece em `sétima`, mas depois da palavra `fogo` está retornando o `�`

Answer (score 1):

Como $dados é um array, Você pode aplicar a função recursivamente com array_walk_recursive:

```
array_walk_recursive($dados, function (&$val) {
    if (is_string($val)) {
        $val = mb_convert_encoding($val, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
    }
});
```

Mas deixando claro que isso é uma gambiarra bem feia... É melhor identificar qual é a fonte desses caracteres unicode incorretos e tratar antes que eles cheguem no PHP.

Comment: Funcionou muito bem para mim essa função mb_convert_encoding!

Answer (score 1):

Sei q é um tópico antigo porem vi em outros lugares muita gente ainda com esse problema, como achei minha solução por aqui aqui vou deixar aqui minha solução, como eu identifiquei o campo que estava me dando problema eu apliquei uma solução focada nele, no caso era o retorno do 'Nome_fornecedor'

```
$stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($result) ; $i++) { 
        $tempCnpj = $result[$i]['CNPJ'];
        $tempFornecedor = json_encode(html_entity_decode($result[$i]['Nome_fornecedor']),true) ;
        $tempData = $result[$i]['efetivado_data'];
        $tempNota = $result[$i]['valor_nota'];
        $arrResposta[$i] = ["Status"=>"true", "Cnpj"=>"$tempCnpj", "Fornecedor"=>$tempFornecedor, "Data"=>"$tempData", "Nota"=>"$tempNota" ];
    }

    echo json_encode($arrResposta);
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize md_convert_encoding() no retorno, segue exemplo:

> $dados = mb_convert_encoding($dados,"UTF-8","auto");
>
> $json = json_encode($dados);

Comment: Dados é um `array`, não vai funcionar desse jeito

Comment: Tentei fazer isso dentro do `foreach`. Não funcionou

Comment: Eu tenho um caso similar e funciona. Podes tentar com utf8_encode() ou dependendo de como retornam seus dados, tente o inverso, utf8_decode()