# Por que a string do php as vezes retorna � no lugar de algumas letras acentuadas?

Tags: php, codificação-de-caracteres

Fiz uma pergunta a respeito de problema de codificação e `json_encode` do PHP.

Para não gerar uma pergunta muito ampla, decidi fazer essa pergunta em separado.

Porque as vezes o PHP retorna o caractere `�` em meio a uma string, contendo caracteres acentuados?

Exemplo:

Meu nome � Wallace

O estranho é que as vezes a mesma letra pode ser substiuída por `�`, sendo que a mesma parece em alguns lugares da string imprimida.

Exemplo:

```
Meu nome � Wallace e estou com fé terei minhas dúvidas resolvidas
```

Observe que o `é` aparece na palavra `fé`, mas ela sozinha não parece.

Por que isso acontece?

O que gera o caractere �?

Comment: Onde acontece isso? Tem algum arquivo, print e etc..?

Comment: @KaduAmaral, veja essa pergunta e vais entender: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91549/json-encode-retornando-malformed-utf-8-characters-possibly-incorrectly-encoded

Comment: Seja a resposta desta pergunta e leia o artigo relacionado, que vais entender. [link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81600/regex-operador-captura-de-meta-caracter)

Comment: esse negócio de ficar usando 30 funções para retornar algo com encoding correto só podia ser obra do PHP

Comment: Qual o encode desse arquivo externo?

Comment: @rray, esse é o problema. Qualquer site que colocar lá, tenho que pegar o conteúdo. Uma hora pode ser utf-8, outra hora pode não ser.

Comment: Então acho que vc detectar o enconde e fazer as verificações, http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-get-encoding.php

Comment: Como explicado na resposta que eu linkei, o problema pode ser incompatibilidade, a pagina que você esta acessando deve ser `ISO-8859-1` e o PHP deve estar em `UTF-8`, assim gerando a incompatibilidade de caracteres.

Comment: @rray, o problema é que algumas página não estou com o utf-8 configurado corretamente. daí a função `mb_detect_encoding` SEMPRE retorna utf-8. Bah!

Comment: Qual é o código utilizado para pegar essa página externa, tem como você colocar na sua pergunta ?

Comment: Provavelmente tem caracteres windows-1251 (ios-8895-1) misturado com Unicode, recomendo esta resposta (que talvez você já conheça): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635 --- será apenas um problema se a resposta vier de um WS, então terá que tratar com `iconv` por exemplo..

Answer (score 1):

Isso ocorre devido ao conjunto de caracteres a qual está configurado sua página web, que deve está divergindo entre outro conjunto. Atualmente temos os conjuntos de caracteres ISO-8859-1 e UTF-8 como os mais usando, sendo que no PHP o recomendável é sempre usar o UTF-8 na codificação de seus scripts.

Dar para alterar o conjunto de caracteres usando o seguinte comando no PHP:

```
<?php
//Sempre coloque esse comando no início do seu script, depois da tag de abertura dele.
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Ou também na página html, usando uma meta tag, assim:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

No html 5 pode-se usar dessa forma:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Na página html ficaria assim:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Seu título da página</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <!- Ou assim em html 5 -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        Conteúdo
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar isso use tudo no mesmo conjunto de caracteres, preferencialmente UTF-8.

Quando digo tudo quero dizer

- O Encoding dos arquivos .php, .js, .css, .html e o que mais puder ter texto.
- O cabeçalho HTML nas tags META
- A codificação do Banco de Dados

Eventualmente pode acontecer de ter que trabalhar com mais de um encoding devido a diferentes origens, como bancos de dados, arquivos como planilhas EXCEL (que só funcionam bem com ISO-8859-1), etc.

Para esses casos use funções de exibição como a esta

```
function toUTF8($string)
{
    if (function_exists('mb_detect_encoding')) {
        $current_encoding = mb_detect_encoding($string, 'UTF-8, ASCII, ISO-8859-1');
        $string = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', $current_encoding);         
    } else {
        $string =  utf8_decode(utf8_encode($string)) == $string ? utf8_encode($string) : $string;           
    }
    return $string;
}

function toLatin1($string)
{
    if (function_exists('mb_detect_encoding')) {
        $current_encoding = mb_detect_encoding($string, 'UTF-8, ASCII, ISO-8859-1');
        $string = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'ISO-8859-1', $current_encoding);            
    } else {
        $string = utf8_encode(utf8_decode($string)) == $string ? utf8_decode($string): $string;     
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Em algumas situações, nem mesmo estas funções resolvem. É o caso de strings concatenadas com mais de uma codificação (acredite, isso não é tão incomum) e para esses casos a conversão deve ser feita caracter a caracter.

Answer (score 0):

Isso ocorre principalmente em retorno de dados do seu banco de dados, pois seu conteúdo pode estar como iso e o dados uft8, ou vice versa.

Tente usar a seguinte função para converter os dados para utf8:

> echo mb_convert_encoding($variavel,"UTF-8","auto");

Lembrando que você deve adicionar a seguinte meta no seu html:

> < meta charset="UTF-8">

Comment: Nesse caso não é o banco de dados. É o conteúdo de uma página external. Não consigo resolver esse problema nem a pau!